# adding calculated column using vba and variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

Depending on some inputs from the users in a user form, I am building code to automatically create calculated columns based on defined criteria. However, I am getting a syntax error in the field expression, code provided below.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Calculate_Click()
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As Recordset
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim Months As Integer
  Dim WPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly written premium
  Dim runningDate As Date
  Dim useDateLower As Date
  Dim useDateUpper As Date
  Dim tdf As dao.TableDef
  Dim fld As dao.Field2


  Months = Me.YearsBack * 12 + Month(Me.ValDate)

  If Me.Period = "monthly" Then

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tblEPdata")

    For x = 1 To Months

      runningDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 1, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
      useDateLower = runningDate
      useDateUpper = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 2, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
      WPmonthly = "WP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
      Set fld = tdf.CreateField(UPRmonthly)
      fld.Expression = "iif([issuedate]<#" & useDateUpper & "#,iif([issuedate]>=#" & useDateLower & "#,[grossPremium]))" ' output gross premium if issue date is between usedateupper and usedatelower, otherwise 0
      tdf.Fields.Append fld
    Next

    MsgBox "added"

  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough arguments for `iif` - it takes three arguments (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)):

```
IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )
```

Judging by your comment in the code, you want either:

```
"iif([issuedate]<#" & useDateUpper & "#,iif([issuedate]>=#" & useDateLower & "#,[grossPremium],0),0)"
```

Or you can simplify this e.g. to:

```
"iif([issuedate]<#" & useDateUpper & "# and [issuedate]>=#" & useDateLower & "#,[grossPremium],0)"
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Get the same error : run time error 3125, " is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long. Error points to tdf.fields.append fld.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The variable wpmonthly was supposed to be used where uprmonthly was being used. uprmonthly was not defined.

Cheers